# Weather application code for API call

Tags: java, android

I have developed a simple weather application that provides the current weather report based on the city provided by the user. Can anyone help me to improve this code?

**`MainActivity`**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

        TextView lblLocation, lblTemperature, lblPressure, lblDescription,
                lblHumidity, lblWind, lblWindDegree;
        EditText txtCity;
        Button btnSubmit;

        String cityStr, temperatureStr, locationStr;
        Context context;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            context = this;

            lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_location);
            lblTemperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_temperature);
            lblPressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_pressure);
            lblDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_description);
            lblHumidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_humidity);
            lblWind = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_wind);
            lblWindDegree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_wind_degree);

            txtCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_city);
            btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
            btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cityStr = txtCity.getText().toString();
            if (cityStr.length() != 0) {
                retriveWeather(context, cityStr);

            } else {
                WeatherAppUtils.showMessage(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter City Name");
            }
        }

        private void retriveWeather(Context c, String city) {
            showProgressDialog(c);
            WeatherAppApi.retriveWeatherByCity(c, city, new OnGetWeatherCallBack() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Weather weather) {
                    if (weather != null) {
                        dismissProgressDialog();
                        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
                        locationStr = weather.getCityStr() +  ", " + weather.getCountryStr();
                        lblLocation.setText(locationStr.toString());
                        temperatureStr = decimalFormat.format(weather.getMaxTemp())
                                + "/" + decimalFormat.format(weather.getMinTemp())
                                + " \u2103";
                        lblTemperature.setText(temperatureStr);
                        lblHumidity.setText(weather.getHumidity() + " %");
                        lblWind.setText(weather.getWindSpeed() + " mph");
                        lblWindDegree.setText(decimalFormat.format(weather.getWindDegree()) + " \u00b0");
                        lblDescription.setText(weather.getDescription());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusFailure(String message) {
                    WeatherAppUtils.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    WeatherAppUtils.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), message);
                }
            });
        }

        private void showProgressDialog(Context c) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
            }
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        private void dismissProgressDialog() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**My interface**

```
public interface OnGetWeatherCallBack {

    public void onSuccess(Weather weather);

    public void onStatusFailure(String message);

    public void onFailure(String message);
}
```

**API class**

```
public class WeatherAppApi {

    private static AsyncHttpClient client;
    private static SyncHttpClient synClient;
    private static PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore;

    private static final String APPID = "APPID=a3db1231e0bb7f98afa2d3ec398e0782";
    private static final String URL_CITY = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";

    private static final String KEY_COD = "cod";
    private static final String KEY_SYS = "sys";
    private static final String KEY_CITY = "name";
    private static final String KEY_MSG = "message";
    private static final String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";

    /* KEYS FOR WIND */
    private static final String KEY_WIND_SPEED = "speed";
    private static final String KEY_WIND_DEGREE = "deg";
    private static final String KEY_WIND = "wind";

    /* KEYS FOR WERATHER */
    private static final String KEY_WEATHER = "weather";
    private static final String KEY_WEATHER_MAIN = "main";
    private static final String KEY_WEATHER_DESCR = "description";

    private static final String KEY_MAIN = "main";
    private static final String KEY_MAIN_TEMPMIN = "temp_min";
    private static final String KEY_MAIN_TEMPMAX = "temp_max";
    private static final String KEY_MAIN_PRESSURE = "pressure";
    private static final String KEY_MAIN_HUMIDITY = "humidity";

    public static void init(Context context) {
        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        synClient = new SyncHttpClient();
        myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(context);
    }

    public static void reInit(Context context) {
        myCookieStore.clear();
        myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(context);
        client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
        synClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
    }

    public static void retriveWeatherByCity(final Context context,
            String cityName, final OnGetWeatherCallBack mCallBack) {
        String url = URL_CITY + cityName + "&" + APPID;
        client.post(context, url, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Weather weather = new Weather();
                try {
                    int cod = response.getInt(KEY_COD);
                    if (cod == 200) {
                        double temperature;
                        weather.setCityStr(response.getString(KEY_CITY));
                        // retrieve the main temperature values
                        JSONObject mObject = response.getJSONObject(KEY_MAIN);
                        temperature = getTemperature(mObject.getDouble(KEY_MAIN_TEMPMAX));
                        weather.setMaxTemp(temperature);
                        temperature = getTemperature(mObject.getDouble(KEY_MAIN_TEMPMIN));
                        weather.setMinTemp(temperature);
                        weather.setHumidity(mObject.getDouble(KEY_MAIN_HUMIDITY));
                        weather.setPressure(mObject.getDouble(KEY_MAIN_PRESSURE));

                        // retrieve the current data for winds.
                        mObject = new JSONObject(response.getString(KEY_WIND));
                        weather.setWindSpeed(mObject.getDouble(KEY_WIND_SPEED));
                        weather.setWindDegree(mObject.getDouble(KEY_WIND_DEGREE));

                        mObject = new JSONObject(response.getString(KEY_SYS));
                        weather.setCountryStr(mObject.getString(KEY_COUNTRY));
                        JSONArray mArray = response.getJSONArray(KEY_WEATHER);
                        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length(); i++) {
                            mObject = mArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            weather.setDescription(mObject.getString(KEY_WEATHER_MAIN));
                        }
                        mCallBack.onSuccess(weather);
                    } else {
                        mCallBack.onFailure(response.getString(KEY_MSG));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                mCallBack.onFailure("Please check your internet Connection");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Method to calculate the temperature
     * 
     * @param d
     * @return
     */
    private static double getTemperature(double d) {

        return d - 273.5;
    }
}
```